# How to configure Nginx in Amazon Linux 2023 based EC2 instance using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, terraform, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have installed DotNet 7.0 and Nginx with the help of User Data Block in my Terraform Script as given below:

```
user_data = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    
    sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/centos/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm
    sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-7.0 -y
    sudo yum install aspnetcore-runtime-7.0 -y
    echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet' >> ~/.bash_profile
    # Load the updated shell configuration
    source ~/.bash_profile
    sudo yum update -y
    sudo yum install -y nginx
    sudo systemctl start nginx
    sudo systemctl enable nginx
EOF

    tags = {
        Name = "${var.env_prefix}-server"
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to configure Nginx to act as a reverse proxy by going through the instructions as guided in Microsoft Official Documentation(Nginx for Linux):
[Click for the Documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=linux-rhel)

As the above documentation says:
**1)** To configure Nginx as a reverse proxy to forward HTTP requests to an ASP.NET Core app, modify /etc/nginx.conf. Update the http{} code block with the following snippet:

```
http {
  map $http_connection $connection_upgrade {
    "~*Upgrade" $http_connection;
    default keep-alive;
  }

  server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}
```

When no server_name matches, Nginx uses the default server. If no default server is defined, the first server in the configuration file is the default server. As a best practice, add a specific default server that returns a status code of 444 in your configuration file. A default server configuration example is:

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
    return   444;
}
```

**2)** The server is set up to forward requests made to http://:80 on to the ASP.NET Core app running on Kestrel at http://127.0.0.1:5000. However, Nginx isn't set up to manage the Kestrel process. systemd can be used to create a service file to start and monitor the underlying web app. systemd is an init system that provides many powerful features for starting, stopping, and managing processes.

**Create the service file**
Create the service definition file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-helloapp.service
```

The following example is an .ini service file for the app:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/helloapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/helloapp/helloapp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So I am try to achieve (1) & (2) with the help of terraform script but its not working moreover its uninstallying nginx and dotnet also I have used user_data, then remote-exec provisiners but unable to achieve the same.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "echo 'http {",
    "  map $http_connection $connection_upgrade {",
    "    \"~*Upgrade\" $http_connection;",
    "    default keep-alive;",
    "  }",
    "",
    "  server {",
    "    listen        80;",
    "    location / {",
    "        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;",
    "        proxy_http_version 1.1;",
    "        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;",
    "        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;",
    "        proxy_set_header   Host $host;",
    "        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;",
    "        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;",
    "        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;",
    "    }",
    "}' | sudo tee /etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
    "",
    "echo 'server {",
    "    listen   80 default_server;",
    "    return   444;",
    "}' | sudo tee -a /etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
    "",
    "sudo systemctl restart nginx"
  ]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("C:/Users/souravs/.ssh/id_rsa")
    host        = self.public_ip
  }
}
```

user_data:

```
user_data = <<-EOF
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "http {
    map \$http_connection \$connection_upgrade {
      \"~*Upgrade\" \$http_connection;
      default keep-alive;
    }
  
    server {
      listen        80;
      location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection \$connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host \$host;
        proxy_cache_bypass \$http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
      }
    }
  }" | sudo tee /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  echo "server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    return   444;
  }" | sudo tee -a /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  sudo systemctl restart nginx
EOF
```

This two did't work!

Comment: What does "This two didn't work!" mean? Any errors? Have you checked the log files on the EC2 instance?

Comment: No Such errors! I believe its crashing the instance, after applying this two no command is working in my instance. Nginx and Dotnet getting uninstalled. Is there is any other way to configure Nginx in Amazon Linux 2023 instance the do let me know. Thanks in advance.